# Swift dynamic cast failed when trying to convert JSON into a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to take the json data that I retrieved and cast it to a Dictionary.

This is my data variable:

```
var data: NSMutableData?
```

This next line keeps giving me a Swift dynamic cast failed error

```
let jsonResult: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Answer (score 3):

The docs / headers tell you that what you will get back from `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` is an `AnyObject?`. You should believe that. It is very foolish to presume that it is a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`. It might be nil; it might be some kind of dictionary, but then again it might be any kind of Foundation object at all. You should treat it as an `AnyObject?`, capture it as such, and then start looking into what it is that you've actually got.